# Having problems understanding following simple algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, if-statement

```java
public class Test1
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        int number = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (number != 0)
            {
                number = i * number;
            }
            else
            {
                number = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println (number);
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure how this algorithm works. My thought process is:

1. We set `number` to 0 by default.
2. In the for loop we are just saying, continue counting `i` till it's no longer smaller than 5.
3. We say that if `number` isn't 0, we update `number` by multiplying it with `i`. So in our case, `i` is 0,1,2,3 and 4.
4. Else we are saying the number is `i` and `i` is what we were counting.
5. Lastly, we print `number`.

Am I missing something? Am I wrong somewhere?

If I run this code why do I get **24** as output? I cannot understand how this simple program works.

Comment: You end up with `4!`. It might help to add `System.out.println(number);` in the loop.

Comment: Your thinking seems to be correct. How about imagining that you are the computer running this code, and think about what you would output?

Comment: the point is that 0 * `x` is equal to  0 for all integers `x`, hence if we would not initialize `number` to something else than `0`, the answer would always be `0`. That is what the `else` branch (i.e. `if (number == 0)`) does. I personally would have chosen another approach (initialize `number` with `1`, start the iteration at `i = 1`, since [0! is 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%21)).

Comment: @Goof If you feel your question has been answered, you may mark one of the answers as accepted (The green tick ✔ symbol near the voting options).

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
public class Test
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        int number = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (number != 0)
            {
                number = i * number;//For i=2, 3, 4
            }
            else
            {
                number = i;//This is executed twice - for i=0 and i=1
            }
        }
        System.out.println (number);
    }
}
```

### Let's understand this program.

1. Execution begins from the `main()` method.
2. A variable named `number` is defined and initialized to `0`.
3. A loop control variable named `i` is defined. Its initial value is `0` and it is increased by `1` at the end of every iteration till it reaches `5`. Note that `i` is never modified inside the loop body.
4. For `i = 0`, the condition `number != 0` is *false*, the else block is executed. `number = i`. The value of `number` remains `0`.
5. For `i = 1`, the condition `number != 0` is *false*, the else block is executed. `number = i`. The value of `number` changes to `1`.
6. For `i = 2`, the condition `number != 0` is *true*, the if block is executed. `number = i * number`. The value of `number` changes to `2`.
7. For `i = 3`, the condition `number != 0` is *true*, the if block is executed. `number = i * number`. The value of `number` changes to `6`.
8. For `i = 4`, the condition `number != 0` is *true*, the if block is executed. `number = i * number`. The value of `number` changes to `24`.
9. Since `i = 5`, the loop breaks. The value of `number` is printed.

This is how we end up getting `24` as the output.

Comment: I would suggest to write-up an answer completely before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

Executing the algorithm step by step will help understanding it.

Let's start with the first line. As you said, this line just sets number to 0.

```
int number = 0;    | number: 0
```

I included the value of the variable on the right side after the bar.
Second step is to start with the loop. Before the loop starts, the counter variable `i` is set to zero.

```
int i = 0;    | number: 0, i: 0
```

As a second step we have to check if the loop criterion is fulfilled, so that the body of the loop will be executed.
The criterion of the loop is `i < 5` and since the current value of `i` is 0 and `0 < 5`, the body of the loop is executed:

```
if (number != 0) {
    number = i * number;
} else {
    number = i;
}
```

Since it is an if statement, we have to see if the if-condition is fulfilled. `number` is currently 0, so `number != 0` is not true. This means we go to the else branch with is:

```
number = i;    | i = 0 -> number = 0
```

Since `i` is zero, number continues to be zero after this statement was executed.
This is the end of the first execution of the loop. Last thing the loop does before restarting is incrementing the counter:

```
i++;    | number = 0, i = 1
```

Now `i < 5` is still true, so the loop body runs again.
We still have `number = 0` therefore `number != 0` is still false.
Note that `i` was updated to 1, but `number` was not until now. Now:

```
number = i;    | i = 1 -> number = 1
```

Now the loop increments the counter and starts anew:

```
i++;    | i = 2
```

Still `i < 5`, so the body of the loop is executed again.
For the first time `number != 0` is true, because `number = 1`.
So now we execute:

```
number = i * number;    | i = 2 -> number = 2
```

`number` used to be 1, `i` is to, so `i * number = 2`
Again the loop body ends, the counter is incremented and the loop restarts, since `3 < 5`:

```
i++;     | i = 3
```

Here again `number != 0`, so we execute

```
number = i * number;
```

which yields `number = 6` since `2 * 3 = 6`.

The same process continues one more time with `i = 4`.
Now `number = 4 * 6 = 24`.
We increment the counter

```
i++;    | i = 5, number = 24
```

Now `i < 5` is no longer true, the loop exits and

```
System.out.println(number);
```

prints the current value of number, 24 to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your thought process was good, but it wasn't exact or detailed enough because the meshing/merging of the sequence of the multiplication (of `number`) with the sequence of incrementing `i` is important.

Work it out on paper with a table, one column per variable, one line per instruction executed:

```
i      number

null   0     int number = 0; // i has not been initialized yet.
0      0     int i = 0;
0      0     number = i;  // it took the else branch
1      0     i++
1      1     number = i;
2      1     i++
2      2     number = i * number
3      2     i++
3      6     number = i * number
4      6     i++
4      24    number = i * number
5      24    i++
5      24    falls out of loop since i < 5 is now false
```